# Save file edits for PDTA?

Tags: save, steam

So, I recently got Please, don't touch anything. I went through all the endings, and totally didn't look online for a few. Now, I want to unlock all the achievements and stuff, and I really don't feel like restarting my game many, many times to get "Perfectionist." I went and extracted the save file. I have moved it over to text edit, and I have no clue what they used to encode it. Here it is:

> Save
>   endings="2D0100001900000000000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F000000000000000000000000"
>   settings
>   volume="1.000000"
>   language
>   language="UK"
>   achieviements
>   perfect_buttons="2742.000000"
>   red_button_all="-40.000000"
>   ach_list="2D0100000A000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>   restarts="103.000000"
>   all_buttons="2693.000000"

Please let me know what I can do to mess around with this save file. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for strange format on code, don't usually use stack exchange for code issues. It didn't approve of the "bad format" that it was originally in.

Answer (score 0):

I was just going through this, so here is what I figured out.
All you have to edit is 'endings' value in savedata.ini file

it looked like this after the first ending:

```
2D0100001900000000000000000000000000F03F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and like this after the second ending:

```
2D0100001900000000000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

first 16 characters are still same, then every 24 characters are for game missions, not sure if zeros count or are just separators:)

```
2D01000019000000
00000000000000000000F03F
00000000000000000000F03F
000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000
...
```

edit that so there is F03F every 24 characters except the last four characters

```
2D0100001900000000000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F00000000000000000000F03F000000000000000000000000
```

you can copy/paste this as endings value and try to run the game. Only the last ending needs to be done and you can get perfectionist achievment ;) (delete save file first, run game once and finish at least one ending so the file is complete)